# Does CAML query support Does Not Contain

Tags: development, csom, caml

I am working on a console application to integrate with SharePoint Online site collection. and I want a way to get all items that do not contain the word "fail" and do not contain the word "success", but I am not sure how I can specify `does not contain` inside CAML. here is my current test code:-

```
CamlQuery camlQuery2 = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery2.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><And><NOT Contain><FieldRef Name='ResultMessage'/>" +
                    "<Value Type='String'>fail</Value></NOT Contain><NOT Contain><FieldRef Name='ResultMessage'/><Value Type='String'>success</Value></NOT Contain></AND></Where></Query></View>";
```

Answer (score 3):

**How I can specify does not contain inside CAML?**

**As a short answer,** Unfortunately, you **CAN'T**.

There isn't `<NOT Contain>` element or any equivalent for `<NOT Contain>` in [Query schema elements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema?redirectedfrom=MSDN#query-schema-elements)

---

**Workarounds**

- You can get the `"<FieldRef Name='ResultMessage'/>"` and perform logical comparing like

  `if (!string.Contains("fail") && !string.Contains("success"))`.

Answer (score 2):

Use`<Neq> </Neq>` instead:

```
<View>  
      <Query> 
         <Where><And><Neq><FieldRef Name='ResultMessage' /><Value Type='Text'>success</Value></Neq><Neq><FieldRef Name='ResultMessage' /><Value Type='Text'>fail</Value></Neq></And></Where> 
      </Query> 
</View>
```

Comment: Neq is different than "not contain".. is this correct?

Comment: Neq means not equal. The caml query would get all items that do not equal "fail" and "success". The same result as "not contain".